# Which field is different using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
df <- data.frame(val1=c(1.2,0.5,3.8,2.5,7.4),
                 val2=c(1.2,2.5,3.8,2.5,2.4),
                 val3=c(1.2,2.5,3.6,2.5,7.4),
                 val4=c(1.2,2.5,3.8,2.5,4.4),
                 val5=c(1.2,2.5,3.8,2.9,7.4))
```

I'd like to find which field is different to the rest. Expecting a result like below to be added to the data frame

```
cbind(df,results = c("all_equal", "val1","val3","val5","morethan1"))
```

Is there any way to do this in an easy way? I have an extensive loop to get this result which I won't post here. I'm looking for a quick solution that I've missed to see (maybe using dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a function to calculate the mode. I used the function found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/7669809

```
Modes <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
}
```

After that, we can use the following code to get the desired output.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  x_mode <- Modes(x)
  if (all(x == x_mode)){
    return("all_equal")
  } else if (sum(x != x_mode) > 1){
    return("morethan1")
  } else {
    ind <- which(x != x_mode)
    return(paste0("val", ind))
  }
})
# [1] "all_equal" "val1"      "val3"      "val5"      "morethan1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` by reshaping the data into 'long' format, apply the conditions to create the 'result' column and then bind the column with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df, 'rn') %>% 
   gather(key, val, matches('^val')) %>% 
   group_by(rn) %>%
   mutate(Mode = Modes(val)) %>% 
   summarise(result = case_when(all(val == Mode) ~ "all_equal",
                           sum(val != Mode) > 1 ~ "morethan1",
                       TRUE ~ paste0("val", which(val != Mode), collapse=","))) %>% 
  select(result) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)
#  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5    result
#1  1.2  1.2  1.2  1.2  1.2 all_equal
#2  0.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5      val1
#3  3.8  3.8  3.6  3.8  3.8      val3
#4  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.5  2.9      val5
#5  7.4  2.4  7.4  4.4  7.4 morethan1
```

The `Modes` function

```
Modes <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
 }
```